# java правильное формирование RequestBody для Post запроса

Tags: java, post, httpclient

Есть сайт, на который я отправляю POST-запрос с английским текстом и в ответ получаю перевод. Вот так выглядит мой код

```
    public void testPromt() throws Exception {
    List<String> dzenArticleUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    String text = "";
    String translatetext = URLEncoder.encode(text, "utf-8");
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    PostMethod post = new PostMethod("https://www.translate.ru/services/soap.asmx/GetTranslation");

    post.addRequestHeader("Host", "www.translate.ru");
    post.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0");
    post.addRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
    post.addRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    post.addRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    post.addRequestHeader("Referer", "https://www.translate.ru/");
    post.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    post.addRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

    post.setRequestBody("{ dirCode:'en-ru', template:'General', text:'Some text from me', lang:'ru', limit:'3000',useAutoDetect:true, key:'123', ts:'MainSite',tid:'', IsMobile:false}");

    post.setRequestBody(body);
    int statudcode = client.executeMethod(post);
    String postRespose = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
}
```

Данный код работает, я получаю перевод. Строка в методе `setRequestBody` полностью скопирована из браузера.
Проблема в том, что метод `setRequestBody` принимающий строку устаревший. Сейчас `setRequestBody` принимает на вход `NameValuePair` . Соответственно я переписал код таким образом:

```
    public void testPromt() throws Exception {
    List<String> dzenArticleUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    String text = "";
    String translatetext = URLEncoder.encode(text, "utf-8");
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    PostMethod post = new PostMethod("https://www.translate.ru/services/soap.asmx/GetTranslation");

    post.addRequestHeader("Host", "www.translate.ru");
    post.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0");
    post.addRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
    post.addRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    post.addRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    post.addRequestHeader("Referer", "https://www.translate.ru/");
    post.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    post.addRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

    NameValuePair[] body = {
            new NameValuePair("dirCode", "en-ru"),
            new NameValuePair("template", "General"),
            new NameValuePair("text", "Some text from me"),
            new NameValuePair("lang", "ru"),
            new NameValuePair("limit", "3000"),
            new NameValuePair("useAutoDetect", "true"),
            new NameValuePair("key", "123"),
            new NameValuePair("ts", "MainSite"),
            new NameValuePair("tid",""),
            new NameValuePair("IsMobile", "false")

    };

    post.setRequestBody(body);

    int statudcode = client.executeMethod(post);
    String postRespose = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
}
```

При отправке statuscode возвращает 500. А в `postResponse` я вижу это `{"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}`
Из-за чего такое может быть, если все параметры `NameValuePair` я указал также, как и в строке `setRequestBody`

Comment: Каким образом вот это `NameValuePair[] body` должно превратиться в это `"{ dirCode:'en-ru', ....., IsMobile:false}"` ?

Comment: @tym32167, этот вопрос скорее к тем, кто этот модуль писал. Однако при дебаге, если открыть body, то они идентичны, что при использовании NameValuePair, что при использовании строки. А как там уже NameValuePair превращается в "{ dirCode:'en-ru', ....., IsMobile:false}" я не вдавался, не могу понять зачем мне этот вопрос был задан

Comment: В рабочем коде вы передаете сюда строку `post.setRequestBody(..)`, в нерабочем вы передаете массив. Очевидно, что проблема в том, что конкретно вы в этот метод передаете, ведь остальной код идентичный, верно? Поскольку код из вопроса написан вами, вот и вопрос мой адресован вам.

Comment: @tym32167, да, Вы правы. Когда код дебажил не тот параметр body отслеживал. Нужно было смотреть во внутрь post, чего я не сделал по невнимательности.

Comment: Вот и здорово. Хорошо, что разобрались.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответом будет замена этого куска кода

```
NameValuePair[] body = {
        new NameValuePair("dirCode", "en-ru"),
        new NameValuePair("template", "General"),
        new NameValuePair("text", "Some text from me"),
        new NameValuePair("lang", "ru"),
        new NameValuePair("limit", "3000"),
        new NameValuePair("useAutoDetect", "true"),
        new NameValuePair("key", "123"),
        new NameValuePair("ts", "MainSite"),
        new NameValuePair("tid",""),
        new NameValuePair("IsMobile", "false")

};
post.setRequestBody(body);
```

на этот

```
post.setRequestEntity( new StringRequestEntity("{ dirCode:'en-ru', template:'General', text:'Some text from me', lang:'ru', limit:'3000',useAutoDetect:true, key:'123', ts:'MainSite',tid:'', IsMobile:false}","application/json","UTF-8") );
```

Спасибо @tym32167 за то, что мне пришлось еще раз внимательнее дебажить код